# Google Sheets - Formula to find difference between two values and recognize if the number difference is positive or negative

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Hope my blabbering will make sense to someone.

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet in Google Sheets to record profits and losses.
I've used the `=ABS(A1-A2)` formula to get the difference between two cell values, but I've noticed that it always returns a positive number.

For Example,
`7.5 - 10 = -2.5`   *but*    `ABS(7.5 - 10) = 2.5`
`10 - 7.5 =  2.5`   *and*    `ABS(10 - 2.5) = 2.5`

Does anyone know a formula or a way for Google Sheets to always return a difference between 2 numbers as a negative number, regardless of which is larger?

For example where:

```
difference(7.5, 10) = -2.5

# and 

difference(10, 7.5) = -2.5
```

Comment: Then why do you use ABS()?

Comment: To add to @Oleg_S point - ABS is a function which takes the ABSolute value of a number, throwing away the sign. You probably just need =A1-A2 with no functions at all.

Answer (score 3):

You said `ABS(A1-A2)`
A1=10.00

and A2=7.50

To find the difference, just do `A1-A2`

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, that was not my question.

My question is: How do I get the the difference between the two numbers to show as "-$2.50" instead of just "$2.50". ABS seems to only find the difference, but it does not record whether the difference is positive or negative.

Comment: @KyleNovakovic ABS() returns absolute value, that's why you get  $2.50 instead of -$2.50. ABS(7.50-10) = ABS(-2.5) = 2.5. You need to simple subtraction A1 - A2

Comment: @Oleg_S Thanks Oleg, but is there no formula to recognise whether is positive or negative automatically? I'm pretty sure Excel has a formula which does that. Does Google Sheets not having anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

### Difference as a negative

There are many approaches that can be used to always return the difference between two numbers as a negative number.  The most obvious is a variation on your current approach with [ABS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093459) since that wouldn't require any conditional logic.  You could also use a conditional [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) function which is longer and unnecessary in this case.

**ABS Function**
As you pointed out, [ABS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093459) always returns a positive number, therefore you can simply convert the number returned by the [ABS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093459) function to a negative value.  In that manner, you will *always* return a negative value without ever needing to know anything about the calculation inside.  This is both the simplest and shortest approach.

```
=-ABS(num1-num2)
```

```
# Examples
+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+
| = -ABS(7.5-10)  | = -ABS(10-7.5)  | = -ABS(10-10)  |
| = -ABS(-2.5)    | = -ABS(2.5)     | = -ABS(0)      |
| = -2.5          | = -2.5          | = 0            |
+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+
```

**IF Function**
The [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) function allows one to conditionally test the numbers and perform subtraction in the preferred order to favor a negative difference.
**Syntax:** `IF(logical_expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)`

<sup>**logical_expression:**  is `num1` smaller than `num2`</sup>
<sup>**value_if_true**:            subtract `num2` from `num1`</sup>
<sup>**value_if_false**:           subtract `num1` from `num2`</sup>

```
=IF(num1<num2, num1-num2, num2-num1)
```

```
# Examples
+-------------+--------+---------+
| logicalTest | ifTrue | ifFalse |
+-------------+--------+---------+
| = IF(7.5<10,  7.5-10,  10-7.5) |
| = 7.5-10                       | # True
| = -2.5                         |
+-------------+--------+---------+
| logicalTest | ifTrue | ifFalse |
+-------------+--------+---------+
| = IF(10<7.5,  10-7.5,  7.5-10) |
| = 7.5-10                       | # False
| = -2.5                         |
+-------------+--------+---------+
| logicalTest | ifTrue | ifFalse |
+-------------+--------+---------+
| = IF(10<10,   10-10,   10-10)  |
| = 10-10                        | # False
| = 0                            |
+-------------+--------+---------+
```

Answer (score -1):

Use an `IF` statement.

Example: `=IF($E$8>E14,$E$8-E14,(E14-$E$8)*(-1))`

Cell `$E$8` is the current stock price.
Cell `E14` is my invested capital

IF the current stock price is higher then my invested capital then `$E$8-E14`.
IF the current stock price is lower then my invested capital then `(E14-$E$8)*(-1)`.

I had to multiply by (-1) to get the negative to show.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:
=IFS(A1>A2,MINUS(A2,A1),A1<A2,ABS(MINUS(A1,A2)),A1=A2, "0")

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Brevity is acceptable but fuller explanations are better.